# LSM303DLHC magnetometer gives wrong Z value

Tags: i2c, pic

The magnetometer options are : continuous measure, range +/-2.5Gauss, output rate = 0.75Hz.

I start by burst reading addresses 0x03 to 0x08 then I convert the result to get the magnetic vector. Everything is fine with both X and Y axis (their values change in accordance with the sensor's orientation) but the Z axis value doesn't make any sense.

My Z value is computed by combining the third (MSB) and the fourth (LSB) byte read, then the result is divided by 0.67 to get the result in mGauss (2.5 Gauss range). This calculation is used for the X and Y axis as well but with good result.

Any idea why my Z value is not correct?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was just a failing sensor.